# CSV から条件を満たした数値だけを抽出したい

Tags: python, csv

このようなcsvファイルに対して、9列目=1.00 のときは3列目を出力し、9列目=0.00 のときは0またはスキップという処理を行いたいです。
excelで行うと `=IF(J2=1,D2,"")` という処理になります。
for文の中でif文を使う部分で躓いております。

[image: csv]

```
import csv

with open('/Users/abc/Desktop/sample.csv', "r") as df1:
    csv.reader(df1)
    for row in csv.reader(df1):
        if row[9] == 1:
            con.append(row[3])
        elif row[9] == 0:
            con.append(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas 使う方法もあります
たいていは数値化してくれるけど, 時々 型指定の必要がある場合も。
また, pandasは 全体的に 素の Pythonとは異なる部分もあり, 人によってはオススメだけど, 合わない人には合わない

(処理の前半は CSVの生成)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
cnt = 10
rng = np.random.default_rng()
with io.StringIO() as fp:
    pd.DataFrame({
        'A': rng.integers(150, size=cnt),
        'B': rng.random(size=cnt) *20,
        'C': np.zeros(cnt),
        'D': rng.choice(a=[0,1], size=cnt),
        }).to_csv(fp, index=False)

    fp.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(fp)    # CSV読み込み, ヘッダー付き

df['val'] = df[df['D'] == 1]['B']   # 該当する項目 'D'が 1の場合は, 'B'の項目をセット
df.style.hide(axis='index').highlight_null(null_color='yellow')
```

[image: 結果]

---

##### 追記

別解(？)として記したけれど, pandas使うのなら, 読んでおくとよいかもなドキュメントあります。

- Cookbook: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html
- Cheat Sheet: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/main/doc/cheatsheet

`IF()` の処理について …

```
excelで行うと =IF(J2=1,D2,"") という処理になります。
```

(上記 Cookbook内に記載あり)

```py
# pandasで同様な処理は, if-then…
df.loc[df.AAA >= 5, "BBB"] = -1

# if-then-else 形式の処理は, NumPyで指定可能
df["logic"] = np.where(df["AAA"] > 5, "high", "low")
```

Comment: 上手く動かすことができました！ご丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

[csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)は文字列(str)として値を読み込むのが原因だと思います。(下記はリンク先抜粋)

> csv ファイルから読み込まれた各行は、文字列のリストとして返されます。QUOTE_NONNUMERIC フォーマットオプションが指定された場合を除き、データ型の変換が自動的に行われることはありません (このオプションが指定された場合、クォートされていないフィールドは浮動小数点数に変換されます)。

文字列と数値をそのまま比較すると正しく比較できず常に`False`となるので、適切にキャストをしてください。

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv', "r") as df1:
    con = []
    csv.reader(df1)
    for row in csv.reader(df1):
        if int(row[9]) == 1:
            con.append(row[3])
        elif int(row[9]) == 0:
            con.append(0)
    print(con)
```

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございました！